# Date error while reading csv file into getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to read a csv file from my local machine using quantmod. I tried the `getSymbols` method but it failed but it seemed to be working when used with `src="yahoo"`.
So I downloaded  a file from yahoo and replaced it with my data.

```
getSymbols("STOCKFUT",src="csv")
```

R is now able to read the file. However when I type:

```
> head(STOCKFUT)
           STOCKFUT.Open STOCKFUT.High STOCKFUT.Low STOCKFUT.Close
2014-03-18         393.70         396.00        388.10          391.65
2014-03-18         392.20         394.95        388.20          391.00
2014-03-18         389.00         389.00        365.00          373.25
2014-03-18         371.60         371.80        357.00          359.10
2014-03-18         359.40         367.45        358.55          365.25
2014-03-18         365.25         370.90        359.30          360.80
           STOCKFUT.Volume STOCKFUT.Adjusted
2014-03-18                0                  0
2014-03-18                0                  0
2014-03-18                0                  0
2014-03-18                0                  0
2014-03-18                0                  0
2014-03-18                0                  0
```

The date is the same throughout the file! Any suggestions on how  I can rectify this?

Comment: I was not able to overcome this problem but I got a workaround using Date conversion function -toDate <- function(x) as.Date(x, origin = "1899-12-30"), z <- read.zoo("STOCKFUT.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = toDate), counterData <- as.xts(z)