# Quantmod not reading dates from csv via getSymbols

Tags: r, csv, quantmod

csv file:

```
"Date","","","","","",
"2014-01-03",1832.98,1838.24,1829.13,1831.37,0,1831.37
"2014-01-06",1831.37,1837.16,1823.73,1826.77,0,1826.77
"2014-01-07",1826.77,1840.1,1828.71,1837.88,0,1837.88
"2014-01-08",1837.88,1840.02,1831.4,1837.49,0,1837.49
```

Command:

```
> getSymbols("SPX3",src="csv")

> SPX3:

           SPX3.Open SPX3.High SPX3.Low SPX3.Close SPX3.Volume
2014-07-23   1832.98   1838.24  1829.13    1831.37           0
2014-07-23   1831.37   1837.16  1823.73    1826.77           0
2014-07-23   1826.77   1840.10  1828.71    1837.88           0
2014-07-23   1837.88   1840.02  1831.40    1837.49           0
           SPX3.Adjusted
2014-07-23       1831.37
2014-07-23       1826.77
2014-07-23       1837.88
2014-07-23       1837.49
```

So, it has loaded everything in correctly except the dates. Anyone know why? By the way, this is the same problem as this guy had ([Date error while reading csv file into getSymbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477637/date-error-while-reading-csv-file-into-getsymbols)) but there was no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setSymbolLookup` to specify that `SPX3` should be read from CSV and ensure the `format` is correct.

```
require(quantmod)
setSymbolLookup(SPX3=list(src="csv",format="%Y-%m-%d"))
getSymbols("SPX3")
```